# Unity+Vuforia+Android - Modification code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I create an simple AR scene. I can run it using webcam and on an Android platform using the `unity` interface.

I want to modify this application code. But I don't know how can I find these files. At 5:39, `Assets is pressed` [on this video](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/Image-Targets-in-Unity). But I don't see any `.cs` file when I press `Assets`

How can I find this file and change my code?

Comment: Please mark the answer if found suitable. Else, comment and let out your thoughts and rectifications. Thank you.

Comment: Please also learn that such questions should use unity3d tag, as the unity is for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CS file you see in that video, is a Custom Script.

-CS stands for a C# Script

-JS stands for Javascript

They have this Custom Script on the Image Target so basically if you want to copy the code, here how you could do it.

- Click on your Image Target, and on the right side, it's Inspector will show. Scroll down the Inspector and you'll see a Add Component.
- Click that and you'll come across a drop down. In the search bar type in New Script, and click the same from the drop down.
- Then enter the name as follows from the video and continue to make sure it's CSharp and not JScript.
- Now when you go to the Assets, you'll see your cs file with the same name you entered, where you can add the same code as the video shows.

> The video basically assumes we know everything. Qualcomm's Vuforia
>   team is the worst when it comes to documentation and hence a lot have
>   sufferred including me, so I hope this helps you. :)